# Avoiding overwriting properties on an object

Tags: c#

I create an object like this:

```
MyObjectClass obj = new MyObjectClass();
foreach( .... )
{
   if( condition1 )
     FillMyObjectWith(obj, "hello", "", "");
   if( condition2)
    FillMyObjectWith(obj, "" , "hello" , "");
}
/////

private void FillMyObjectWith(MyobjectClass obj, string val1, string val2, string val3)
{
  obj.Field1 = val1;
  obj.Field2 = val2;
  obj.Field3 = val3;
}
```

Notice I have **not** used an `"else"` for if conditions because in that `for each loop` there are cases that both conditions can also be `true`, so when `condition1` is `True` I pass "hello" to `Field1` and pass blank to the other two fields, when `condition2` is true I pass "hello" to `Field2` and blank to the rest of the fields.
The problem is if both conditions are true the last call overwrites the "hello" value of one of the fields with empty string.
How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp There are ALSO situations that maybe just one of them is true...so I want "hello" to be populated for that Field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are only setting one value on each condition and leaving the rest to blank so one way is to change your method signature to only accept three arguments. One carries the value you want to set and one is an `Enumeration` that you flag it to show where is the value is getting assigned then in your method check for that `Enum` and assign the value based on that.

```
FillMyObjectWith(MyobjectClass obj, string val1, Enum )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
private void FillMyObjectWith(MyobjectClass obj, string val1, string val2, string val3)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val1))
            obj.Field1 = val1;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val2))
            obj.Field2 = val2;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val3))
            obj.Field3 = val3;
    }
```

or

```
private void FillMyObjectWith(MyobjectClass obj, string val1, string val2, string val3)
    {
        obj.Field1 = val1 ?? string.Empty;
        obj.Field2 = val2 ?? string.Empty;
        obj.Field3 = val3 ?? string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: but if I don't pass value to some arguments, I still want them to be string.empty in the object properties.

Comment: +1. As long as there is safe "not there" value for elements this is reasonable approach (works perfectly using  nullable for value types like `int?`)... This will not work for reference types when null is valid value for the property.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
foreach( .... )
{
   if ( condition1 && condition2)
      FillMyObjectWith(obj, "hello", "hello", "");
   else if( condition1 )
      FillMyObjectWith(obj, "hello", "", "");
   else if( condition2)
      FillMyObjectWith(obj, "" , "hello" , "");
}
```

Comment: +0: and for 3 conditions `2^3-1` conditions... does not really scale past 2 conditions case (where inline `? :` probably would work better)...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Do you mean `FillMyObjectWith(obj, condition1 ? "hello" : "", condition2 ? "hello" : "", "")`?

Comment: Yes, something like that - if formatted on each line will probably be readable... (Also there is probably much better solution in C# style rather than reimplementing `JQuery.extend`, maybe fluid interface like `MyobjectClass SetFieled2WhenTrue(bool condition, string value)` ).